# How to tar compress specific and multiple files without changing of name in Bash?

Tags: bash, tar

I need do some simple compresion multiple files to .tar in bash.
Conditions:
My archive must include only files with extension .exe.
Unfortunetly, when I am trying this:

```
find ./myDir -name "*.exe" | tar -cf archive -T -
```

The file names are changed like ./file1.exe How can I compress this without change of file names?

Comment: `tar` by design always includes a path name. The file name is not really "changed" per se.

Comment: Do you want the whole path to each file removed, or just the leading `./`?  If the former, then is everything you want to archive in `./myDir`, or are there deeper subdirectories to take into account?

Comment: Note also that by default, `tar` creates an *uncompressed* archive.  If you want compression then you have to specify one of the options that tells `tar` what type to use, or else to compress the archive separately, after the fact.

Comment: are you able to enter the dir 'myDir' and run  <find . -name "*.exe" | tar -cf archive -T -> or < find . -name "*.exe" -exec tar -cf archive.tar {} \+> ? If yes, you only have the filenames in archive. If not, you can copy all found files in a tmp dir and run a tar command in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Suggesting:

```
 find "$PWD/myDir" -name "*.exe" | tar -cf archive -T -
```

This will not do anything interesting.

#### Better suggesting to feed `tar` command with results from `find` command

```
  tar czf your_compressed_file.tar.gz $(find ./myDir -name "*.exe")
```

Notice `tar cf` is not compressed. But `tar czf` is compressed.

You can also add `-v` option to see what are the compressed files:

```
  tar czfv your_compressed_file.tar.gz $(find ./myDir -name "*.exe")
```